# Where should Stored Proc business logic be placed in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for a bit of experience and explanation here, given that different sources give different recommendations.  I am totally new to MVC.  I know this question has been asked before, but I am not (currently) using EF or Linq.

I have a SQL database with many stored procedures.  Previously when used with webforms, there was a business layer that contained helper methods for calling the procedures and returning DataSets to the pages.  The important part is that the procedures often interrogated about 20 tables; **the pages do not simply reflect the database structure exactly** (as I see in the majority of MVC tutorials):

```
SQL database <--> stored procedures <--> business layer <--> web forms
```

I want to take the best approach here to start on the right footing and learn properly but appreciate there may not be a *correct* answer.  Therefore if you post, could you please offer some explanation as to "why"?

---

- Should stored procedure logic (SQLCommand/business methods etc) go within Model or
  Controller?

[One post advises neither](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9810028/792888), but retain the business layer.  [Another expert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843323/792888) advises that

> [Models/Entities] should not have any addon methods outside of what's
>   coming back from the database

- If the business layer is retained, where are the methods called from (e.g. Model or Controller)?
- If the above answer is "Neither", does that mean the Model part will go unused?

That almost feels that things aren't being done *properly*, however in [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En) that appears to be what happens.

- Should I plug in the Entity Framework into the Model layer to call the business layer?

That feels like overkill, adding all that additional logic.

Comment: As with all things this depends on how much effort you want to put in. Proper layers and separated concerns/unit testing is probably overkill for a single page tiny application. I've answered this question assuming you want to do things the "right" way even if it is a small example project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controllers should gather the information required to build the page the user is currently viewing. That's it.

Controllers should reference classes in your business logic layer.

For example here's your controller. All it does is translate the http request and call the business logic.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private IMyBusinessLogic  _businessLogic;
   public MyController(IMyBusinessLogic businessLogic)
   {
      _businessLogic = businessLogic;
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UpdateAllRecords()
   {
      _businessLogic.UpdateAllRecords();
      return Json(new Success());
   }
}
```

And your business logic class

```
public class MyBusinessLogic : IMyBusinessLogic  
{
  public void UpdateAllRecords()
  {
    // call SP here
    using(SqlConnection conn = new...
  }
}
```

There are a number of advantages to this:

- Your business logic is completely separated from your UI, there's no database code in your presentation layer. This means your controller can focus on it's job and code doesn't get polluted.
- You can test your controller and see what happens when your business logic succeeds, throws exceptions etc.

For extra bonus points you should look into creating a data access layer.

```
public void DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
  public void RunStoredProcedure(string spName)
  {
  }
}
```

Now you can test that your BLL is calling and processing your SP results correctly!

**Expanded following the comment questioning the models:**
Ideally your model should have no logic in it at all. It should simply represent the data required to build the page. Your object which you're loading represents the entity in the system, the model represents the data which is displayed on the page. This is often substantially lighter and may contain extra information (such as their address) which aren't present on the main entity but are displayed on the page.

For example

```
public class Person
{
   public int  PersonID {get;set;}
   public string Firstname {get;set;}
   public string Lastname {get;set;}
   public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

The model only contains the information you want to display:

```
public class PersonSummaryModel
{
   public int  PersonID {get;set;}
   public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

You then pass your model to your view to display it (perhaps in a list of FullNames in this case). Lots of people us a mapper class to convert between these two, some do it in the controller.

For example

```
public class PersonMapper
{
  public PersonSummaryModel Map(Person person)
  {
     return new PersonSummaryModel
     {
       PersonID = person.PersonID,
       FullName = string.Concat(person.Firstname, " ", person.Lastname)
     };
  }
}
```

You can also use some automatic solutions such at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to do this step for you.

Comment: Thanks @Liath.  I need to return an object to the controller (of type <MyObject>).  I had put this in a Model, but you're saying it should actually be in the DAL referenced via BL/Controller?  This would actually mean that the Model layer across the application is pretty much unused (apart from a login model).  Does that sound normal?

Comment: @EvilDr I've expanded my answer to talk about Models too

Comment: @EvilDr but yes, load your entities from the business logic/data access and let your controller adapt them to show them on the page. This may seem like a lot of classes but it makes life a LOT easier when projects start to grow and you want to test things

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.  Yesterday I followed a tutorial to create a login page (http://bit.ly/VSa8gj).  Based on your point, *"your model should have no logic in it at all"*, is the tutorial code not that well written then (user model contains lots of logic)?  This is partly where my confusion about structure is coming from...

Comment: @EvilDr big chunks of that look great, personally I'm not sure about the having IsValid method in the model. If I was writing that I'd make that call from the controller method into the business logic because I don't like UI classes accessing the database. Different Devs different approaches!

Comment: That's great, thank you for helping me to start getting my head around the MVC behemoth... (and if you want a job... :-) )

Comment: @EvilDr Haha, no problem! I think there's a steeper learning curve than asp.net but it's very powerful and clean once you're up and running

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should really only be involved with orchestrating view construction. Create a separate class library, called "Data Access Layer" or something less generic, and create a class that handles calling your stored procs, creating objects from the results, etc. There are many opinions on how this should be handled, but perhaps the most

```
View
|
Controller
|
Business Logic
|
Data Access Layer
|--- SQL (Stored procs)
       -Tables
       -Views
       -etc.
|--- Alternate data sources
       -Web services
       -Text/XML files
       -and son on.
```

if you feel like learning tiers and best way
MSDN have  great article on this link 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973279.aspx)